# Is there a way to make my own save command that overrides the standard file save keybind?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command

I'm contributing to an open issue regarding keybindings and custom editors. More specifically, if one were to edit a Markdown file in the standard `.md` text editor then hit `CMD+S`, not only does VSCode save the edits on the open file, but it also toggles to the Markdown's preview mode.

Right now, I have a custom editor save command in the works, and the constructor/keybindings is as follows (in TypeScript):

```js
(new class SaveCustomEditorCommand extends Command {
    public static readonly ID = 'editor.action.customEditor.save';

    constructor() {
        super({
            id: SaveCustomEditorCommand.ID,
            precondition: CONTEXT_HAS_CUSTOM_EDITORS,
            kbOpts: {
                primary: KeyMod.CtrlCmd | KeyCode.KEY_S,
                weight: KeybindingWeight.EditorContrib
            }
        });
    }
    ... // fully implemented runCommand function
}).register();
```

As the command is, hitting `CMD+S` simply saves the changes and nothing more. However, if I were to change the KeyCode from KEY_S to **KEY_Y** (since `CMD+Y` isn't an already existing keybinding command), the save-to-preview command works as intended. Setting the `weight` property inside `kbOpts` to higher enums does **not** change anything.

I'm certain that somewhere in VSCode source, the File/Save `CMD+S` command takes total precedence, but given that my command should be running only under the precondition that the context has custom editors, I was wondering if I can somehow force my "Save and Preview" command to run instead of the simple, universal "Save" command.

Any pointers or guidance would be much appreciated; this is my first contribution to anything open-source!

If keeping `CMD+Y` is the more feasible course of action for a "Save and Preview" keybinding, then that works for me, but I would like to least try with `CMD+S` if possible.